# SparkContext SubmitJob to submit a Spark job

Tags: apache-spark

How can I use SparkContext.[submitJob](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext@submitJob.html) to submit a new job in Apache Spark.